# jQuery ui-dialog layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a way to remove this space?

[image: jquery ui-dialog box]

```
jQuery ui-dialog
```

Find this at http://jsfiddle.net/sumanthreddy/bps6e/8/

Comment: Your fiddle link isn't giving the same output...
http://screencast.com/t/MR7QCijVjztu

Comment: @SethMcClaine.. plz chk now

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in css

```
#rolling {
   height: 80px !important;
}
```

http://screencast.com/t/VNpe7ODkh2Ar

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
#cancel, .buttonDiv {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;   
    right: 5px;
}
```

And for the love of cousin skeeter, please use shorthand and compact that entire CSS file.  Here's a freebie.

This (yours):

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
border-top-color: #2ba1b5;
border-bottom-color: #2ba1b5;
border-left-color: #2ba1b5;
border-right-color: #2ba1b5;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
background-color: rgb(231,238,249);
```

That (mine):

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 0;
clear: both;
border: 1px solid #2ba1b5;
background: rgb(231,238,249);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this line in your `initializeDevice` function, at last line

```
jQuery("#rolling").dialog('open');
```

Just change it to

```
jQuery("#rolling").dialog('open').css('height', '90px'); // or less
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/bps6e/9/)
But, you can do it using `css` as well and answers are already given on that.